# read int and char array from file, then resize array

Tags: c, arrays, windows, malloc, realloc

I am learning to manipulate arrays. I store element by element data read from file into char and int array in a function outside main() named readInput(). Data read:

D  E  D  D  E  E E D E  E  E D E

21 32 35 59 58       16 11     29

I attempt to resize both arrays to exclude garbage in the arrays with realloc: My questions:

- When printing the char array in main(), it contains the right elements but prints garbage at the end of the array. I note it prints correctly at readInput(). What did I do wrong?
- At readInput() before and after realloc, and in main(), the elements read from file of the int array are correct except they are followed by garbage. What did I do wrong?

Output:

Print from readInput() - Char Array before realloc: D E D D E E E D E E E D E

Print from readInput() - Int Array before realloc: 21 32 35 59 58 16 11 29 -8421
50451 -842150451 -842150451 -842150451 -842150451 -842150451 -842150451 -8421504
51 -842150451 -842150451 -842150451 -842150451 -842150451 -842150451 -842150451

Print from readInput() - Char Array after realloc: D E D D E E E D E E E D E

Print from readInput() - Int After after realloc:21 32 35 59 58 16 11 29 -336860
19 -842150451 739749649 37763 4849560 4849264 -842150451 -842150451 -842150451 -
842150451 -842150451 -842150451 -842150451 -842150451 -842150451 -842150451 -842

Print from main() - Char Array (after realloc): D E D D E E E D E E E D E   ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═
═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ² ² ² ² ³ Î £ ` w º
É · y   É V t   ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ═ ² ² ² ² and it goes on

Print from main() - Int Array (after realloc): 21 32 35 59 58 16 11 29 -33686019 -842150451 874388096 31426 6946712 6946416 -842150451 -842150451 -842150451 -842150451 -842150451 -842150451 -842150451 -842150451 -842150451 -842150451 -842150451 -842150451 and it goes on

Context of the program:
The read data is stored in a function outside main() named readInput(), char by char/int by int into a char and int arrays respectively that are declared and initially sized via malloc in main().

After storing data in the arrays, I need to re-size the arrays to the size of the data read in the file.

Finally, to verify the array is also accessible to main , write char by char and int by int the arrays both in main() and readInput().

Thank you for your help.
Edited corrected working code, thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

//prototypes
void openFile(char *fileNames, FILE **inputFilePointer);
void closeFile(FILE **inputFilePointer);
void readInput(char *choiceArray, int *valueArray, int *charArraySize, int *intArraySize, FILE **inputFilePointer);
void memCharReallocation(char **choiceArray, int requiredArraySize);//resize char array to what's actually required after reading the file
void memIntReallocation(int **valueArray, int intSize);//resize int array to what's actually required after reading the file

void main()
{
    char *charArray =NULL;
    int *valueArray;
    int inputSize;
    int charInputSize = 0;//size of elements read from file
    int intInputSize = 0;//size of elements read from file

    //file read/write variables
    FILE *iFilePointer;//file pointer
    char *filename = "inputFileTest.txt";

    //open and read Files
    openFile(filename, &iFilePointer);

    //initial mem allocation to size char and int array
    valueArray = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 100);
    if (valueArray == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nCould not allocate memory, exiting.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    charArray = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
    if (charArray == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nCould not allocate memory, exiting.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    //read file and allocate to array
    readInput(charArray, valueArray, &charInputSize, &intInputSize, &iFilePointer);

    //print char array: Test I can read it here too
    printf("\nPrint from main() - Char Array: ");
    for (int j = 0; j<charInputSize; j++)
    {
        printf("%c ", charArray[j]);
    }
    //Print int array
    printf("\nPrint from main() - Int Array: ");

    for (int j = 0; j<intInputSize; j++)
    {
        printf("%d ", valueArray[j]);
    }
}

//read data from file
void readInput(char *readCharArray, int *readValueArray, int *charArraySize, int *intArraySize, FILE **inputFilePointer)
{
    int i, j = 0;//loop variables
    char *pbuffer = NULL;//buffer to read input file
    int bufferSize = 200;//max initial size for buffer
    char *token = NULL;////tonize
    char ch = NULL;//convert string char to char
    int readingChar = 0;//flag we are reading char from file

    //alloc memory to pbuffer
    pbuffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*bufferSize);
    if (pbuffer == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nCould not allocate memory, exiting.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Read Input From File: \n");
    //store each element from file in struct variable
    while (fgets(pbuffer, bufferSize, *inputFilePointer) != NULL)//read each line from file
    {
        j = 0;//reset array to subscript zero on each pass
        //tokenize file data
        for (token = strtok(pbuffer, " "); token != NULL; token = strtok(NULL, " "))
        {
            //char token
            if (isalpha(token[0]))
            {
                ch = token[0];
                readCharArray[j++] = ch;
                readingChar = 1;//flag we are reading char from file to get length of array excl array garbage
            }
            //int token
            else if (isdigit(token[0]))
            {
                readValueArray[j++] = atoi(token);
                (*intArraySize)++;
            }

            else
            {
                printf("\nCan't read file\n");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        if (readingChar)
        {
            readCharArray[j] = '\0';//remove excess cells on array
            *charArraySize = strlen(readCharArray);//size of array
            readingChar = 0;//end of reading char from file
        }
    }

    //print char array: Test 1
    printf("\nPrint from readInput() - Char Array before realloc: ");
    for (int j = 0; j < *charArraySize; j++)
    {
        printf("%c ", readCharArray[j]);
    }
    //Print int array
    printf("\nPrint from readInput() - Int Array before realloc: ");
    for (int j = 0; j < *intArraySize; j++)
    {
        printf("%d ", readValueArray[j]);
    }

    memCharReallocation(&readCharArray, charArraySize);
    memIntReallocation(&readValueArray, intArraySize);

    printf("\nPrint from readInput() - Char Array after realloc: ");
    for (int j = 0; j < *charArraySize; j++)
    {
        printf("%c ", readCharArray[j]);
    }
    printf("\nPrint from readInput() - Int After after realloc:");
    for (int j = 0; j < *intArraySize; j++)
    {
        printf("%d ", readValueArray[j]);
    }
}

void memCharReallocation(char **charArray, int requiredArraySize)//resize int array to what's actually required after reading the file
{
    char *ptempArray = NULL;

    ptempArray = (char*)realloc(*charArray, requiredArraySize * sizeof(char*));

    if (ptempArray == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not allocate memory, exiting");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        *charArray = ptempArray;

    if (ptempArray != *charArray)
        free(ptempArray);
}

void memIntReallocation(int **valueArray, int intSize)//resize int array to what's actually required after reading the file
{
    int *ptempArray = NULL;

    ptempArray = (int*)realloc(*valueArray, intSize* sizeof(int*));

    if (ptempArray == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not allocate memory, exiting");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        *valueArray = ptempArray;

    if (ptempArray != *valueArray)
        free(ptempArray);
}

void openFile(char *fileNames, FILE **inputFilePointer)
{
    printf("\n\n");
    //open files and error mssg
    if ((*inputFilePointer = fopen(fileNames, "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Can't open input file %s\n", fileNames[1]);
        exit(1);
    }
}

void closeFile(FILE **inputFilePointer)
{
    //close files
    fclose(*inputFilePointer);
}
```

Comment: When you do `sizeof` on a pointer, you get the size of *the pointer*, not what it points to. Now think about the expression `sizeof(*valueArray) / sizeof(int)` in the `memIntReallocation` function.

Comment: `readInput` doesn't return anything

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I’ve edited the code. I calculate the number of elements for the int Array as I read the data from file and pass this value to realloc. Same problems outlined remain.

Comment: @Ôrel thanks a bunch for pointing this, the intent is for readInput() to write the arrays and make these accessible to other functions. I've edited above to void readInput() and updated the persistent erroneous result behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, warnings are not to be ignored.

> ```
>  void main(char *argv) {
>         ...
>         argv = ...;
> ```

should have raised one (CLang even gives an error!) because it is not conformant C. It should be:

```
int main() {
    ...
    char *filename = ...;
```

Do not declare argv if you do not use it and avoid using `argv` for anything else than command line parameters.

Next: `for (int j = 0; j < charArray!=NULL; j++)` should also raise tons of warnings. You first compare `j` and `charArray` (already undefined behaviour). After seeing the result, `j < charArray` happens to be true (value 1 in C) and you compare it to NULL which is a `void *`! `1 != 0` is always true and you get a never ending loop.

`for (int j = 0; j < charSize || readValueArray[j] != NULL; j++)` should also raise warnings: `readValueArray[j]` is an `int` and `NULL` is a `void *`. In addition, it is no use testing `readValueArray[j]` to `0` because you have never initialized the allocated memory.

Finally resize does not *remove garbage from the array* it reallocates the array with the asked size somewhere in memory, and if you access past the allocated memory you just invoke Undefined Behaviour. There is no way in C to know the size of an array, it is the programmer's job to care for it.

So you have 2 possible ways here:

- either pass the actual size of the arrays as an (output) parameter of `readInput`:

  ```
  void readInput(char *choiceArray, int *valueArray, FILE **inputFilePointer,
      int *choiceArraySize, int *valueArraySize)
  ```
- or use a special value (for example 0) as an end marker.

And *please* pay attention to warnings!

Comment: Thanks a a lot @Serge Ballesta, passing arraySize works, I've modified the code above accordingly. Can I please clarify: (a) where you say comparing readValueArray[j] to 0 is of no use because I never initialized the allocated memory - why is that if the array was indeed successfully reallocated and I understand readValueArray does not need re-initializing, it's the existing array for the new size after realloc. (b) what is the difference between reallocating memory to the size of an array and changing the size of an array?

Comment: @SergioSolorzano a/ After malloc, the allocated memory contains unspecified data, not necessary 0; you must set zero it explicitely if you want to be able to identify cells that have never received a new value. b/ I cannot understand what your are asking. An array may have 2 sizes, the allocated one and the used one. You have to keep track of both and you can change the allocated one with `realloc` - but in fact, `realloc` *may* move the array at a different address.

Answer (score 0):

In the body of  `while (fgets(pbuffer, bufferSize, *inputFilePointer) != NULL)`
you used same variable `j` as array index for both `readCharArray` and `readValueArray` ,i think this will crate problem during assignment since it get incremented during each assignment some index values won't be used. use two variables separately for `readCharArray` and `readValueArray`.